# Spring Interceptor to scan and deserialize all Enums to one Json

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I am working on a project with Java(Spring Boot) backend and Angular4 for frontend.

My challenge is to sync all java enums with Angular. For example I have PhoneType enum in server. When I am sending CustomerInfo object to the front-end by REST API, phone type will be a string "MOBILE". 
So we should have duplicate enum in Angular to avoid hardcoding strings.

I was thinking to create an interceptor and scan all enums with specific annotation I have defined and deserialized all values inside enum and create single Json file.

First, please correct me if we have better solution and second, how I can create interceptor to scan all root source package and fins enum classes with specific annotation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not understand your requirement properly.
The way to introduce a Interceptor which scans classes with any annotation under a package is as below.

```
public class Interceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse){
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
        provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(YourCustomAnnotation.class));
        provider.setResourceLoader(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classLoader));
        for (BeanDefinition bd : provider.findCandidateComponents("com.your.basePackage"))
        {
            // Do Something
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@EnableWebMvc   
public class App extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {  
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new Interceptor());
    }
}
```